# Is it possible to detect message type in protobuf-csharp-port?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

A java client constructs a Message according to this skeleton :

```
package tutorial;

option java_package = "com.example.sff.piki2";
option java_outer_classname = "MsgProtos";

message MSG {

 required string guid = 1; 
 required int32 MsgCode = 2;
 required int32 From = 3;  //sender
 ...
```

This message is sent to a C# program ( server side).

The server knows how to read the bytes ( *first byte is the number of bytes to read which represents the size of the following message* ).

This is how MSG is being constructed by a byte array.

```
 MSG Msg = MSG.CreateBuilder().MergeFrom(buffer).Build();
```

Where buffer is the byte array which read from the socket.

But now I'm in a situation where a client needs to send "Heartbeat" message(  *another* message) in order to check if the server is alive or not. ( the server should respond : *"yes i'm alive"*)

Sure , I can add another field to the `MSG` class. but I don't want to because the `MSG` class has a lot of unnecessary fields  - for a Heartbeat operation.

**Question :**

The server read n bytes. Is there anyway I can know if this is a `MSG` message or a "Heartbeat" message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can know if this is a MSG message or a "Heartbeat" message?

No. Protocol buffer messages don't contain any such type information. Typically the way round this is to have a "wrapper" type with a field for each message you *might* want to send. You'd ideally want to express this as a [`oneof`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof), but my port doesn't support that (yet).

The overhead is minimal - but it will be a protocol change, of course, so you'll need to think about any existing servers etc.